# Cant open Android Studio after install

Tags: android-studio

Forget to create shortcut during install, and i cant find bin folder on installation folder, how i can open android studio again on ubbuntu[image]

Answer (score 0):

Useinng the Command line:

1. Navigate into the root directory `cd /`
2. then, navigate into Android Studio directory using
   `cd /snap/android-studio/97/android-studio/bin`   or navigate into it manually
3. Run `./studio.sh`