# "The application “Android Studio” can’t be opened. 255 " on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-big-sur, finder

[image]

I can't open Android Studio Application on Mac. How can I solve this?

1. I've deleted `studio.vmoptions` file in Contents > bin. But didn't work.
2. I deleted Android Studio, And reinstalled it. But the same error causes.
3. I deleted Android Studio with CleanMyMac and retried.
4. I deleted Android Studio with these commands.

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

But all of them didn't work.

And I read these. But didn't help.

[macOS "The application Android Studio can't be opened"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610620/macos-the-application-android-studio-cant-be-opened)

[Cant open Android Studio after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912886/cant-open-android-studio-after-install)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue. The only thing that worked for me was going to the download options (https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) and getting the .dmg installer

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions worked for me, but I manage to start the app with:

```
sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```